# Is Eka Nadi Dosha does not exist for the boy and girl born in the Rohini and Uttara Ashadha Nakshatras

Tags: marriage, astrology, nakshatra, horoscopes, nadi

I entered Boy and Girl horoscope details in website to check whether marriage is compatible or not. In one website, i got it is not compatibe to due eka nadi dosha but in another it showed **eka nadi dosha** is cancelled as in below image :

[image]

So is really The Eka Nadi Dosha does not exist for the boy and girl born in the **Rohini** and **Uttara Ashadha** Nakshatras / **Ashlesha** ?